# exec failed with fork() and execvp()

Tags: c, linux, fork

I am currently working on a program in which I have to write a shell in C. I am having trouble getting the fork() section of my program to work. Here is my code:

```
void execute_func(char** tok)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    
    if (pid == -1)
    {
        printf("\nERROR: forking child process failed\n");
        return;
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        if (execvp(tok[0], tok) < 0)
        {
            printf("ERROR: exec failed\n");
        }
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        wait(NULL);
        return;
    }
}
```

for example, if I am to type in any sort of function such as "ls" or "wc" it gives me the "ERROR: exec failed" message, which means that the fork() is not running correctly. This could be a small issue in my understanding of fork() but I am completely stumped.

here is my whole program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

char str[129];
enum {NOT_FOUND=0,FOUND};
enum {false=0,true};
static char *ptr;
const char *del;
int ReadLine(char *, int , FILE *);




char *mystrtok(char* string,const char *delim)
{
    int j,flag=NOT_FOUND;
    char *p;
    if(string != NULL)
    {
        ptr=string;
        p=string;
    }
    else
    {
        if(*ptr == '\0')
        return NULL;

        p=ptr;
    }

    while(*ptr != '\0')
    {
        del=delim;
        while(*del != '\0')
        {
            if(*ptr == *del)
            {
                if(ptr == p)
                {
                    p++;
                    ptr++;
                }
                else
                {
                    *ptr='\0';
                    ptr++;

                    return p;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                del++;
            }
        }
        ptr++;
    }
    return p;
}

void execute_func(char** tok)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    
    if (pid == -1)
    {
        printf("\nERROR: forking child process failed\n");
        return;
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        if (execvp(tok[0], tok) < 0)
        {
            printf("ERROR: exec failed\n");
        }
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        wait(NULL);
        return;
    }
}
    


int main()
{
    int i;
    char *p_str,*token;
    char delim[10];
    delim[0] = ' ';
    delim[1] = '\t';
    delim[2] = '\n';
    delim[3] = '\0';
    char cwd[1024];
    char *tok[129];

    while(1)
    {
        tok[0] = NULL;
        fflush(stdin);
        fflush(stdout);
        printf("\n Enter a string to tokenize: ");
        //    printf("\n before scan");
        fflush(stdin);
        //    printf("\n fflush");
        ReadLine(str, 128, stdin);
        /*    scanf("%[^\n]",str); */
        printf("\n after scan");

        for (i = 1, p_str = str; ; i++, p_str = NULL)
        {
            token = mystrtok(p_str,delim);
            if (token == NULL)
            break;
            printf("%d: %s\n",i,token);
            tok[i-1] = token;
            printf("%s\n",tok[i-1]);
        }
        if(tok[0] != NULL)
        {
            if(strcmp(tok[0],"cd") == 0)
            {
                if (chdir(tok[1]) != 0)
                    perror("chdir() error()");

                getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
                printf("current working directory is: %s\n", cwd);
            }

            else if(strcmp(tok[0],"pwd") == 0)
                if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) == NULL)
                    perror("getcwd() error");
                else
                    printf("current working directory is: %s\n", cwd);

            else if(strcmp(tok[0],"exit") == 0)
                exit(3);

            else
            {
                execute_func(tok);
            }
        }
    }       
}


int ReadLine(char *buff, int size, FILE *fp)
{
    buff[0] = '\0';
    buff[size - 1] = '\0';             /* mark end of buffer */
    char *tmp;

    if (fgets(buff, size, fp) == NULL) 
    {
        *buff = '\0';                   /* EOF */
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
        /* remove newline */
        if ((tmp = strrchr(buff, '\n')) != NULL) 
        {
            *tmp = '\0';
        }
    }
return true;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [complete minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We need to see how this function is called. Maybe `tok` doesn't have the right content. Also, call `perror` for a more specific error msg.

Comment: @kaylum I have edited in my main function where I'm calling the function in question.

Comment: Please read the link. The code you have provided is neither complete nor minimal. If you try and create a minimal example, for example by removing the user input and hard coding the string, you mean even find the problem yourself.

Comment: @kaylum I don't see why you need the rest of my code. My problem lies in the function itself, as the fork() command is not working how I intended.

Comment: How do you know that? By definition you are here because you don't know where the problem is. That function looks correct. The problem more likely lies in the fact that the token parsing has a problem. What is the output from your debugs? And what is the output from `perrror` if you call it in the error case?

Comment: @kaylum i have edited in my entire program

Comment: Please provide an example of the input you provide your program.

Comment: @TonyB I have edited it in

Comment: The `tok` array needs a NULL pointer as its last element, as stated in the documentation for `execvp`.  I don't see where you add it.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Was typing that up as answer ...

Answer (score 3):

Problem appears to be here:

```
        if (token == NULL)
        break;
        printf("%d: %s\n",i,token);
        tok[i-1] = token;
```

The trailing `NULL` never gets set in `tok` thus resulting in `execve` not finding the end of the list. Like this should fix it:

```
        tok[i-1] = token;
        if (token == NULL)
        break;
        printf("%d: %s\n",i,token);
```

Comment: this fixed it. thank you. most of this code was a template given by a professor, and that was part of it.